# super resolution of low resolution images using delaunay triangulation, negative pixel values for the resultant High resolution image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, polynomial-math, delaunay, matlab-cvst

i have to do super resolution of two low resolution images to obtain a high resolution image.

2nd image is taken as base image and the first image is registered with respect to it . i used SURF algorithm for image registration . A Delaunay triangulation is
constructed over the points using a built-in MATLAB delaunay
function . The HR grid of size is
constructed for a prespecified resolution enhancement factor R Then HR algorithm for interpolating the pixel values on the
HR grid is summarized next.

HR Algorithm Steps:
1. Construct the Delaunay triangulation
over the set of scattered vertices in the
irregularly sampled raster formed from the
LR frames.

1. Estimate the gradient vector at each
   vertex of the triangulation by calculating the unit normal vector of neighbouring vector using cross product method.Sum of the unit normal vector of each triangle  multiplied by its area is divided by summation of area of all neighbouring triangles to get the vertex normal.
2. Approximate each triangle patch in
   the triangulation by a continuous and,
   possibly, a continuously differentiable
   surface, subject to some smoothness constraint.
   Bivariate polynomials or splines
   could be the approximants as explained
   below.
3. Set the resolution enhancement factor
   along the horizontal and vertical directions
   and then calculate the pixel value
   at each regularly spaced HR grid point to
   construct the initial HR image

The bivariate polynomial i used is mentioned in the code, using pixel values at each vertex of a triangle and corresponding gradient in x and y directions i calculated the nine constants associated with each triangle then defined a high resolution grid , calculated the pixel values at each point using the constants calculated

i am attaching my code with it, the problem i am facing is that i am just getting a gray image as out put HR image , because the constants i have calculated have negative values resulting in negative pixel values

another problem i realized with my code is in gradient estimation i get a lot of 'NaN' as a result of gradient calculation.

if any one can please spent some time to help me out

```
close all
clear all
K = 2;
P1 = imread('C:\Users\Javeria Farooq\Desktop\project images\a.pgm');
%reads the image to be registered
P2 = imread('C:\Users\Javeria Farooq\Desktop\project images\b.pgm');
%reads the base image
 image1_gray = makelr(P1, 1, 100, 1/2);
%image1_gray = P1;
% makes lr image of first
 image2_gray= makelr(P2, 1, 100, 1/2);
%image2_gray= P2;
%makes lr image of second
figure(1),imshow(image1_gray)
axis on;
grid on;
title('Unregistered image');
figure(2),imshow(image2_gray)
axis on;
grid on;
title('Base image ');
impixelinfo
% both image displayed with pixel info
hold on
points_image1= detectSURFFeatures(image1_gray, 'NumScaleLevels', 100, 'NumOctaves', 12,  'MetricThreshold', 500 );
%detects surf features of first image
points_image2 = detectSURFFeatures(image2_gray, 'NumScaleLevels', 100, 'NumOctaves', 12,  'MetricThreshold', 500 );
%detects surf features of second image
[features_image1, validPoints_image1] = extractFeatures(image1_gray, points_image1);
[features_image2, validPoints_image2] = extractFeatures(image2_gray, points_image2);
%extracts features of both images 
indexPairs = matchFeatures(features_image1, features_image2, 'Prenormalized', true) ;
 % get matching points
matched_pts1 = validPoints_image1(indexPairs(:, 1));
matched_pts2 = validPoints_image2(indexPairs(:, 2));
figure; showMatchedFeatures(image1_gray,image2_gray,matched_pts1,matched_pts2,'montage');
%matched features of both  images are displayed
legend('matched points 1','matched points 2'); 
 % Compute the transformation matrix 
tform = estimateGeometricTransform(matched_pts1,matched_pts2,'projective')
%calculate transformation matrix using projective transform
T=tform.T;
r=[];
A=[];
l=1
[N1 N2]=size(image2_gray)
registeredPts = zeros(N1*N2,2);
% s= zeros(N1*N2,2);
pixelVals = zeros(N1*N2,1);
[N1 N2]=size(image2_gray)
for row = 1:N1
    for col = 1:N2
        pixNum = (row-1)*N2 + col;
        pixelVals(pixNum,1) = image2_gray(row,col);
        registeredPts(pixNum,:) = [col,row];
    end
end

[r]=transformPointsForward(tform,registeredPts);
%coordinates of base image
image2_gray=double(image2_gray);
R=2;
r1=r(:,1);
r2=r(:,2);
for row = 1:N1
        for col = 1:N2
            pixNum = N1*N2 + (row-1)*N2 + col;
            pixelVals(pixNum,1) = image1_gray(row,col);
            registeredPts(pixNum,:) = [r1(row,1),r2(row,1)];
        end
    end
% all pixel values are saved in pixelVals
%all registered points are saved first base image then unregistered image
%delaunay triangulation of all coordinates passing x and y coordinates from registered Points 
 tri = delaunay(registeredPts(:,1),registeredPts(:,2));
figure(3), triplot(tri,registeredPts(:,1),registeredPts(:,2))
save tri
% Estimate the gradient vector at each vertex
[totalTris,three] = size(tri);
[totalPoints,two] = size(registeredPts);
vGradientVecs = zeros(totalPoints,2);
triAreas = zeros(totalTris,1);
triUnitNormals = zeros(totalTris,3);
vUnitNormals = zeros(totalPoints,3);
%   1. Find the unit normal vectors and the areas of all triangles,
%      then find the product of these two numbers for each triangle
for triNum = 1:totalTris
    v = tri(triNum,:);
    % 3D triangle points: x,y,pixel
    b=pixelVals(v);
    b=b(:);
    p = [registeredPts(v,:),b];
    % triangle area
    triAreas(triNum) = polyarea([p(:,1)],[p(:,2)]);

    % directional vectors representing the surface of the plane
    d1 = p(2,:)-p(1,:);
    d2 = p(3,:)-p(1,:);

    % cross product of these vectors
    crossp = cross(d1,d2);

% If u = [u1 u2 u3] and v = [v1 v2 v3], we know that the product w is defined as w = [(u2v3 – u3v2) (u3v1 - u1v3) (u1v2 - u2v1)]
    % normalized cross product = unit normal vector for the triangle
    dist = sqrt(sum(crossp.^2));
    triUnitNormals(triNum,:) = crossp./dist;
end

%   %2. %Estimate the unit normal vector at each vertex
%       a. Find the triangle patches that neighbor the vertex
%       b. Find the unit normal vectors of these regions
%       c. Multiply each of these vectors by the area of the 
%          associated region, then sum these numbers and divide
%          by the total area of all the regions

 for pointNum = 1:totalPoints
    [neighbors,x] = find(tri==pointNum);
    areas = triAreas(neighbors);
    areas3 = [areas,areas,areas];
    triNormsSum = sum(triUnitNormals(neighbors,:).*areas3);
    triAreasSum = sum(areas);
     vUnormalized = triNormsSum./triAreasSum;
        vUnitNormals(pointNum,:) = ...
        vUnormalized./sqrt(sum(vUnormalized.^2));
    if( triAreasSum == 0 )
        triAreasSum = 0.0001;
    vUnormalized = triNormsSum./triAreasSum;

    % re-normalize
    vUnitNormals(pointNum,:) = ...
        vUnormalized./sqrt(sum(vUnormalized.^2));
end

%   3. Find the gradients along the x and y directions for each vertex
%      vertex's unit normal: n = [nx,ny,nz]
%      x-direction gradient: dz/dx = -nx/nz
%      y-direction gradient: dz/dy = -ny/nz
% 
 for pointNum = 1:totalPoints
    nz = vUnitNormals(pointNum,3);
    if( nz == 0 )
        nz = 0.0001;
    end
    vGradientVecs(pointNum,1) = -vUnitNormals(pointNum,1)./nz;
    vGradientVecs(pointNum,2) = -vUnitNormals(pointNum,2)./nz;
% end
 end
 end
%   1. Find the 3 equations for each vertex, and
%      place them in c_equations matrix;
% c_equations = [A for vertex 1;
%                A for vertex 2; ...
%                A for vertex totalPoints]
% c(point,row,:) gives one row from an A matrix
 Btotal = zeros(3,totalPoints);
 c_equations = zeros(3*totalPoints,3,9);
 for pointNum = 1:totalPoints
%     % B = [pixVal; x gradient; y gradient] at this vertex
 z = pixelVals(pointNum);
     B = [z; vGradientVecs(pointNum,1); vGradientVecs(pointNum,2)];
%     
%     % Compile all B matrices into a vector
     Btotal(:,pointNum) = B;

    % B = Ac to calculate c which is c=[c1 c2 .....c9]' take invA and
    % multiply by B
    x = registeredPts(pointNum,1);
    y = registeredPts(pointNum,2);
    A = [1   x   y   x^2  y^2  x^3     (x^2)*y  x*(y^2)  y^3; ...
         0   1   0   2*x   0   3*(x^2)  2*x*y   y^2      0; ...
         0   0   1   0    2*y  0        x^2     2*x*y    3*(y^2)];

    % Compile all A matrices into a vector
    c_equations(pointNum,1,:) = A(1,:);
    c_equations(pointNum,2,:) = A(2,:);
    c_equations(pointNum,3,:) = A(3,:);
end

%   2. Find the c values for each triangle patch
c = zeros(totalTris,9);
c9 = zeros(9,9);
for triNum = 1:totalTris
    p1 = tri(triNum,1);
    p2 = tri(triNum,2);
    p3 = tri(triNum,3);

    B9 = [Btotal(:,p1); Btotal(:,p2); Btotal(:,p3)];
    c9 = [(c_equations(p1,1,:)); (c_equations(p1,2,:)); (c_equations(p1,3,:)); ...
          (c_equations(p2,1,:)); (c_equations(p2,2,:));( c_equations(p2,3,:)); ...
          (c_equations(p3,1,:)); (c_equations(p3,2,:));( c_equations(p3,3,:))];
      C9=squeeze(c9);
    c(triNum,:) = pinv(C9)*B9;   %linsolve(c9,B9);

end
% xc = findBPolyCoefficients1(tri,registeredPts,pixelVals,vGradientVecs);
% save xc
% %   2. For each point on the HR grid, find the associated triangle patch,
% %      extract its c values, and use these values as the coefficients
% %      in a bivariate polynomial to calculate the HR pixel value at
% %      each grid point (x,y)
[N1,N2]=size(image1_gray);
[totalTris,three] = size(tri);

M = N1*R-1;
N = N2*R-1;
HRimage = zeros(M,N);
HRtriangles = zeros(M,N);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:1/R:N2,1:1/R:N1);

% Check all the triangles in order noting in which triangle each HR
% grid point occurs.
for triNum = 1:totalTris
    pts = registeredPts(tri(triNum,:),:);
    IN = inpolygon(X,Y,pts(:,1),pts(:,2));  % NxM
    HRtriangles(ind2sub(size(IN),find(IN==1))) = triNum;
end
% there is  a problem with this part of code , 
for y = 1:M % row
    for x = 1:N   % col  
        % For testing, average the pixels from the vertices of the
        % triangle the HR point is in.
%         pix = pixelVals(tri(HRtriangles(x,y),:));
   %      HRimage(x,y) = (pix(1) + pix(2) + pix(3))/3;
        % Extract appropriate set of 9 c values
         HRptC = c(HRtriangles(x,y),:);
         % Bivariate polynomial
    HRimage(x,y) = sum(HRptC.*[1,x,y,x^2,y^2,x^3,(x^2)*y,x*(y^2),y^3]);
         g(x,y)=HRimage(x,y);
        %changd xy with yx
    end
end
%   HRimage = estimateGridVals1(tri,registeredPts,R,N1,N2,pixelVals);
% %Estimating Grid values at each patch
%  %save HRimage

     g(g(:,:)<0)=0;
figure(8),imshow(g,[]);
```

Comment: i have to add the code

Comment: What language? I'm guessing Matlab and have tagged accordingly, so please correct if wrong.

Comment: its matlab thank you and i realized a problem that in this particular line of code   for pointNum = 1:totalPoints
    [neighbors,x] = find(tri==pointNum);   ,which is meant to check all the triangles so that it can locate the neighbouring triangles to each vertex, at points such as 14200 point there are neighbouring triangles but this command returns an empty matrix, i checked in command window it first gives many triangles and at once at end makes it neighbor=empty matrix, i cannot figure out why

Comment: yes i tried imagesc but due to NaN values just traces were displayed of original image